.NET 8 / EF Core 8 doesn't recognize geography type from the PostGIS extension
My ASP.NET Core 8 Web API & EF Core 8 app doesn't recognize the geography type from the PostGIS extension. This is the error I get :

System.InvalidCastException: Reading as 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point' is not supported for fields having DataTypeName 'public.geography'

As the extension was installed in the public schema, I tried changing the search_path to include "public" but it still didn't work.
Here are the installed extensions
                                  List of installed extensions
    Name     | Version |   Schema   |                        Description                         
-------------+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 aws_commons | 1.2     | public     | Common data types across AWS services
 aws_lambda  | 1.0     | public     | AWS Lambda integration
 plpgsql     | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis     | 3.4.2   | public     | PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions
 uuid-ossp   | 1.1     | public     | generate universally unique identifiers (UUIDs)

This is how the data type is mapped in the entity class:
[Column("spatiallocation", TypeName = "geography")]
public Point? SpatialLocation { get; set; }

This is how the DbContext is registered:
services.AddDbContext<GeodataDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseNpgsql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("GeodataConnectionString"),
                    b => b
                        .UseNetTopologySuite()
                );
            });


The error Reading as 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point' is not supported for fields having DataTypeName 'public.geography'  seems to indicate there is mismatch between geometry and geography types. You might look at Geography (geodetic) Support here (https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nts.html?q=postgis&tabs=datasource)

Double-check that the search path is correctly set to include the public schema. You can set the search path in your PostgreSQL configuration or via the connection string like so:
services.AddDbContext<GeodataDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql("Host=myserver;Database=mydb;Username=myuser;Password=mypassword;Search Path=public",
        b => b.UseNetTopologySuite());
});

Or you can do it in SQL wherever the PostGIS extension is installed:
SET search_path TO public;


Thanks, adding search path to the connection string works.
